# How to export data from database to a textfile using linq

Tags: c#, database, linq, text-files

I wonder how to export data from a *DataBase table* to a *text file* using Linq.

The database table name is `Customer` and columns are `CustomerID` and `Customername`.

I use `StreamWriter` and I want to fill the text file with the data that's in the database table `Customer`.

This works - **but** this exporting from `DataGridView`

```
 private void bExportEKsystem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.txt", true);

     int rowcount = DataGridview1.Rows.Count;
     for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
     {
         sw.WriteLine();
     }

    sw.Close();    
 }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the code you have written yourself.

Comment: How are you accessing your database?

Comment: I've edited now. I'm accessing the databse throught linq/.dbml-class

Comment: It seems you are exporting from a datagridview, not a table...

Comment: Yes, but i want it to export from datatable!!How do i do that?

Comment: You can do something like this:


IEnumerable<Customer> customers = from customer in db.Customers select CustomerId, CustomerName;


and then:



TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);

customers.ForEach(c => sw.WriteLine(c.ToString());



Where you define your Customer.ToString to print out customer info in  your preferred format...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = from customer in db.Customer 
    select CustomerID,   Customername;

using(TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
{
    foreach (var c in customers)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    }
}
```

Where you define your Customer.ToString to print out customer info in  your preferred format...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
        int rowcount = datagridview1.Rows.Count;
        IEnumerable<string> output = datagridview1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select( row => (string) row.Cells[0].Value + row.Cells[1].Value);
        using(TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
        {
            foreach (string s in output)
            {
                   sw.WriteLine(s);
            }            
        }
```

*edit: it's better to use the using statement for the Stream